# Sustain object instance on AngularJS page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have created a simple app using AngularJS and Firebase. Below is the code shown to login a user using Firebase as back end.

```
loginObj.$authWithPassword({
    email: username,
    password: password
})
.then(function(user) {

}, function(error) {

});
```

On clicking the logout button I use the same `loginObj` instance to log out the user.

```
loginObj.$unauth
```

The problem occurs when I refresh the page after login. Since the loginObj instance has been lost, `loginObj` is null and hence unable to logout.
Can any one point out how to handle this scenario.

Comment: I think you can call `$unauth` on any AngularFire object (and `unauth` on and Firebase ref). So if you can't ensure logout before the refresh, you can probably just do it as the first call when you create the new ref.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you mean that when doing logout, I really don't need the same `loginObj` instance which I used for login. Can I simply create a new instance and logout ?

Comment: Yup. You're not authenticating a single Firebase reference, but the entire session. If the client is picking up the authentication when the page reloads, that mean that it was able to restore the auth token from local storage. Calling `unauth` will make it forget that token.